# Hello world llvm-lit with cfg file

Tags: testing, llvm

I'm trying to run a simple test with llvm-lit. I have a dedicated directory:

```
llvm-lit-dir
+---lit.cfg
+---llvm_lit_example.c
```

The cfg file is from llvm-3.8.0/utils/lit/lit/ExampleTests.ObjDir.
Here it is:

```
$ cat lit.cfg
config.example_obj_root = os.path.dirname(__file__)
lit.load_config(config, os.path.join(config.test_source_root,'lit.cfg'))
```

Here is the example I'm trying to check:

```
$ cat llvm_lit_example.c
// RUN: %clang -o %t0 %s
// RUN: %t0 | grep "YES"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i=rand()%4;

    char s1[5]={'0','1','2','3', 0 };
    char s2[5]={'0','1','2','3', 0 };

    s1[i]='6';

    if (strcmp(s1,s2) == 0) printf("NO \n");
    if (strcmp(s1,s2) != 0) printf("YES\n");
}
```

I've tried several options but none seem to work:

```
$ llvm-lit llvm-lit-dir/llvm_lit_example.c
llvm-lit: TestingConfig.py:114: fatal: unable to parse config file '/home//llvm-lit-dir/lit.site.cfg', traceback: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/llvm-3.8.0/llvm/utils/lit/lit/TestingConfig.py", line 101, in load_from_path
  exec(compile(data, path, 'exec'), cfg_globals, None)
File "/home/llvm-lit-dir/lit.site.cfg", line 14, in <module>
  lit.load_config(config, os.path.join(config.test_source_root,'lit.cfg'))
NameError: name 'lit' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The following is the minimalistic "hello world" example which is now working for me:

config file: **lit.cfg**

```
import lit.formats

config.name = "LIT hello world"
config.test_format = lit.formats.ShTest("0")
```

test file: **tests/test**

```
; RUN: echo "Foo" | FileCheck %s
; CHECK: Foo
```

run it with

```
lit -v tests/test
```

To make the test fail, change it to `echo "Bar"`.

---

Two additional comments:

1) Installing `lit` is easy:

```
pip3 install lit
```

To install `FileCheck` I had to download LLVM source code ([LLVM Download page](http://releases.llvm.org/download.html)) and build the `FileCheck` target using CMake.

2) `config.test_format = lit.formats.ShTest("0")` is important because otherwise lit fails with the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'execute'
```

It looks like [ShTest](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/utils/lit/lit/formats/shtest.py) is a default format, but a user still has to activate it manually.

Answer (score 1):

This config is a python source. `lit` there is clearly undefined. Try importing something related to lit, like `from lit.llvm import llvm_config`. Take a look at `test/lit.cfg.py` in LLVM source.

Comment: I've tried copy-pasting stuff from the test/lit.cfg file, but I keep getting errors :((

Comment: @Brian the errors are posted in the last section of the post: " ... fatal error ..."